# Configuring a Virtex-5 FPGA over USB?

Tags: usb, bga

I am working on a project with a Virtex-5 FPGA, the only method for uploading bitstreams is over JTAG, if I remember correctly; is it possible to do it any other way? I am trying to save space on the PCB.

Comment: When you say "uploading code and so on," what exactly do you mean? Do you mean to download the configuration bitstream? Or do you want a USB interface to your FPGA design?

Comment: BGA is a *package type*, not a description of what the chip does! What are you ultimately trying to do with it, make a custom USB device of some kind?

Comment: If I am correct, the FPGA's I am using use JTAG to transfer the compiled C code, I was hoping to be able to do that over a usb interface? to save space on my PCB.

Comment: Will edit that.

Comment: Many of the larger parts have multiple different ways of loading bitstreams. JTAG is easiest for development, but in production you can have it load from e.g. serial EEPROM.

Comment: So, Xilinx has Embedded USB/JTAG controllers that allow you to access the JTAG configuration interface. These chips make it like the FPGA's configuration interface is a USB device. But I'm still not sure that is what you are looking for. "Compiled C code" sounds like an executable for a CPU. But they aren't on chip.

Comment: Sorry, I had meant to say Bitstreams? relatively new to BGA's not sure what the correct terminology would be.

Comment: https://store.digilentinc.com/all-products/jtag-programmers/

Comment: @Alex: keep in mind that a Xilinx USB configuration circuit (which definitely exist, take a look at just about any Xilinx dev board) is comprised of several components, and will be larger than a JTAG connector. So doing this for size reasons is probably useless. But for convenience, this is a valid question. (I clarified your question, hopefully I didn't change the meaning).

Comment: It was what I had meant to say, thank you. it is also for convenience.

Comment: The assertion "the only method for uploading bitstreams is over JTAG" is incorrect. See page 15 of http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug191.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking for, then no. what you are asking for does not exist. Also, your answer above makes no sense. Xilinx' "XPS USB 2.0 EHCI Host Controller" is a piece of IP for connecting USB to your embedded design. That doesn't appear (to me, at least) to be what you are looking for.

Comment: My bad, I just noticed after answering it. Damn, thats annoying what is the recommended way to interface a BGA with USB?

Comment: @Alex: typically, you would use either a dedicated USB controller chip, or a microcontroller with built-in USB. Also, "BGA" is a package, "FPGA" is a type of integrated circuit. FPGAs may come in BGA packages, but other types of chips do as well.

Comment: Technically, you *could* have the EHCI controller in your FPGA design, and establish a connection to that controller that writes data to the FPGA's attached configuration ROM, and then have the FPGA reboot itself from the ROM. But every new design you load into the FPGA would have to include that capability as well, or else you will end up "bricking" it, requiring a JTAG programmer to get it going again. This is akin to having a serial bootloader preprogrammed into an MCU.

Comment: ...  I regularly work on FPGA designs that can update their own configuration ROMs over various interfaces. But I still do most of the development with a JTAG programmer, because it's a lot more convenient.

Comment: I think I will stick to JTAG. I could integrate a USB to JTAG converter on the PCB?